# Signal all processes in process group except self

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc

I am writing a program which multiple processes will run concurrently. In this program, there is a need for one process to suspend all other participants temporarily.

In order to spare myself the overhead of tabulating all participant process ID's in a shared page and signaling them individually, I have created a process group that all participants join.

To suspend all processes in a group, I initially used the call:

`killpg(0, SIGSTOP);`

and intended to resume them after with:

`killpg(0, SIGCONT);`

I have quickly realized though, that this also suspends the calling process, as long as it too is a member of the process group. Because any process should be able to suspend the other members of the group, I cannot dedicate one process for this task. My question, thus, is whether there is a system call or mechanism to suspend all group members with the exception of the caller. I am looking for something specifically for Linux.

Comment: You can't catch SIGSTOP, but you can catch SIGTSTP-- so send SIGTSTP but temporarily ignore it in the sender.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Are you proposing I install handlers for all processes, and then attempt to infer whether I am supposed to suspend execution or continue? Is there perhaps a quick way to temporarily disable a signal without a handler?

Comment: No need for a handler.  Default disposition for SIGSTSP is the same as SIGSTOP.  Just ignore the signal in the sender, then send, then restore default disposition.  `man sigignore`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Why not make this an answer.

Comment: @alk Because it doesn't answer the question of how to send a signal to all members of the group except one.  The answer to that question (I believe) is "you can't".

Comment: I'm personally fine with accepting a workaround, and an ignore (`SIG_IGN`)/unignore (`SIG_DFL`) combo with `sigaction` qualifies for me. However, I *was* asking for an existing mechanism or syscall like @WilliamPursell mentioned, and so if you all feel it's best I wait for an authoritative answer to that then I'll refrain from accepting the workaround solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send a signal to all members of the group except the sender, but there is a reasonable workaround.  Rather than using `SIGSTOP` (which cannot be handled or ignored), you can use `SIGTSTP` which by default will have the same effect as `SIGSTOP`, stopping the process which receives it.  To avoid stopping the sender, simply have the sender ignore the signal before it is sent, and then reset the signal disposition to the default after sending signal to the process group.